# Custom flutter calendar

Tags: flutter, calendar, border

I need to draw a calender in my Flutter Android/IOS app. The result has to be the following:

[image]

I've found some libraries, but no one allowed to customize borders.
I tried to create it using a [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html), but it does not allow to have different styles of border. With [Gridview](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) I have not been able as well.

Does somebody have a sample or some hints?

Edit:

Using [table_calendar](https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-calendar):

I suppose it is using a Table since the borders are not collapsed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Calender package for it. Below links will helpful to you

[Simple calender](https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-calendar)

[Table calender](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar)

[Syncfusion calender](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar/example)

P.S :- I suggest to you that go with Syncfusion. In that you can get many variation in calender

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. Actually, Simple calendar is using table calendar, and I suppose it is using a Gridview, I updated my question (the borders are not collapsed). Syncfusion is not for free, it requires a paid license.

Comment: So you want simple calender with no border. Am I getting right?

Comment: I need a calendar where I can have different borders per cell, linke the first image of my question.

Comment: For that you need to calender customization , because you don't get your desired calender through flutter calender packages

Comment: ...as I thought :/

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to be useful, but here's how I accomplished this using the [table_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) package.

The package only exposes the table border via `TableCalendar.calendarStyle.tableBorder`, which affects everything, including the week days.

If you can ignore the week days, you can just do this:

```dart
TableCalendar<T>(
  ...
  calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
    tableBorder: TableBorder.all(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer),
    ...
  ),
)
```

---

If you do, however, care about the days of the week, then you can try the hack below.

It's not perfect. In my case, I was using `TableCalendar.calendarStyle.outsideDaysVisible == false`, so artifacts of the misaligned border in the first and last days of the month can be seen, but it was good enough for my use-case.

##### Constraints of my use-case

- First day of the week is Monday
- I don't display outside days (the days before the 1st of the month, after the last day of the month)

##### The concept

The idea is to only render the top and right borders for every day.

This way, no two days will share a border on the same side - which gives the borders that bumpy look, since they aren't collapsed.

If you only do this, however, the first day of the month and every Monday will not have a left border, so we need to accommodate for that (edge-case 1).

Similarly, the days in the last week of the month will not have a bottom border (edge-case 2).

#### Step 1: define a tile wrapper that will be applied on every day

```dart
Widget dayTileWrapper(
  DateTime day, {
  required ThemeData theme,
  required Widget child,
}) {
  return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        top: BorderSide(color: theme.colorScheme.primaryContainer),
        right: BorderSide(color: theme.colorScheme.primaryContainer),
        // Edge-case 1
        left: day.weekday == 1 || day.day == 1
            ? BorderSide(color: theme.colorScheme.primaryContainer)
            : BorderSide.none,
        // Edge-case 2
        bottom: isPartOfLastWeek(day)
            ? BorderSide(color: theme.colorScheme.primaryContainer)
            : BorderSide.none,
      ),
    ),
    child: child,
  );
}

bool isPartOfLastWeek(DateTime date) {
  const aDay = Duration(days: 1);
  final lastDayOfMonth = DateTime(date.year, date.month + 1).subtract(aDay);
  return lastDayOfMonth.difference(date).inDays < 7;
}
```

#### Step 2. Add it to the calendar builders

You can accomplish this in one of two ways:

- add it to each builder individually (`todayBuilder`, `selectedBuilder`, `defaultBuilder` and so on)
- add it to the `prioritizedBuilder`

Here's an example of how the latter could look like (I'm using [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) here for simplicity):

```dart
TableCalendar<T>(
  ...
  calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
    prioritizedBuilder: (context, date, focused) {
      return dayTileWrapper(
        date,
        theme: Theme.of(context),
        child: Text(DateFormat.d().format(date)),
      );
    },
    ...
  ),
)
```